# How do I communicate with a RS232 serial port on a remote device using TCP/IP?

Tags: java, serial-port, javax.comm

I have a device connected using a serial port to [GC-100-12](http://www.globalcache.com/products/gc-100/models1/). I want to connect to it remotely and pass commands to that device and retrieve replies from that device. I am capable of communicating if the device is connected straight to my laptop but I would like to allow for the device to not be physically connected as well.

I am using `javax.comm` to communicate with the serial device when connected locally.

**EDIT:**

It appears that the GC-100-12 I am using is an appropriate hardware solution as outlined by David. I simply opened a socket connection along with the port for the RS232 port and passed in commands as an array of bytes and voila!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use hardware solution. Something like [this](http://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/Serial-over-IP/2-Port-RS-232-Serial-Ethernet-IP-Adapter-Device-Server-Console-Server~NETRS232_2).

Given it's quite expensive, you may consider looking at Rasperry PI or even Arduino-based solution.

Comment: I was afraid of that. +1 for the answer and varied solutions.

Comment: What is range to device? Maybe RS422 would help?

Comment: If you mean the distance between me and the device in question, less than a a meter, although obviously in practice it could be more than that.

Comment: If it's within 1.5km, RS422 may be an answer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-422#Characteristics

Comment: Please do not answer with a link and no other explanation. At least summarize what is at the other end of the link.

Comment: @mickeyf I think the link URL containing words /Networking-IO/Serial-over-IP/2-Port-RS-232-Serial-Ethernet-IP-Adapter-Device-Server-Console-Server~NETRS232_2 tends to be quite self-explanatory even if you don't follow it.

Comment: @DavidJashi The reader does not see all that. The see the word "this" unless they click on the link, which may be dead when they see it months or years later. In cases like that the answer is completely useless.